# Facing issue in triggering keypress event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to fire <kbd>Tab</kbd> key's `keypress` event on a specific condition, but I'm getting error.

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: event.initKeyEvent is not a function

#### Code

```js
function simulateKeyPress(element) {
  console.log("Simulate")
  var event = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent'); // create a key event

  // define the event
  event.initKeyEvent("keypress", // typeArg,
    true, // canBubbleArg,
    true, // cancelableArg,           
    null, // viewArg,  Specifies UIEvent.view. This value may be null.
    false, // ctrlKeyArg,
    false, // altKeyArg,
    false, // shiftKeyArg,
    false, // metaKeyArg,
    9, // keyCodeArg,
    9); // charCodeArg);
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function keyPress(event) {
  simulateKeyPress(this);
}

(function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("keypress", keyPress);
  }
})()
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

I have been taking following links for reference but still unable to get it working.

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) - Answer given by @Philip Nuzhnyy
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent)

Following is the link of [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/e7p69mhq/)

#### Edit

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/e7p69mhq/2/) that uses `KeyboardEvent`, but still unable to fire `Tab` keypress event.

Also, I'm not looking for jQuery.

Comment: Its not available now 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent

Comment: You can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: @AnandSingh [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). Both `KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent` and `KeyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent` have been marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 console.log(typeof (event.initKeyEvent)); // returns undefined
```

and MDN docs say :

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
> browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
> Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
> break at any time.
>
> Do not use this method any more, use the KeyboardEvent() constructor
> instead.

Comment: I have updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/e7p69mhq/2/). Now error is now thrown but `Tab` is not getting fired. I suppose there is some silly mistake. Can you please help?

Comment: Also I was a bit confused with `keyCode`, `charCode` and `code`.